# How to display UTC time in vega-tooltip "version": "0.5.1",

Tags: vega

I use "utc" vega scale in order to display data in UTC time, but when I hover an item in the chart then tooltip show a date in local format. How to display UTC data in vega tooltip?

Here is vega tooltip config

```
        let options = {
        showAllFields: false,
        fields: [
            {
                field: "x",
                title: "Time",
                formatType: "time",
                format: "%x %X "+ this.props.data.Timezone
            },
            {
                field: "y",
                title: "Value",
                formatType: "number"
            },
            {
                field: "value",
                title: "Time",
                formatType: "time",
                format: "%x %X "+this.props.data.Timezone
            },
            {
                field: "label",
                title: "Data",
                formatType: "string"
            },
            {
                field: "info",
                title: "Info",
                formatType: "string"
            },
            {
                field: "startTime",
                title: "Start",
                formatType: "time",
                format: "%x %X "+this.props.data.Timezone
            },
            {
                field: "endTime",
                title: "End",
                formatType: "time",
                format: "%x %X "+this.props.data.Timezone
            }
        ]
    }
    vegaTooltip.vega(vegaView, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't judge about the data of dates you ingest, but this was discussed recently in https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/pull/1053.

The core of the matter is that you'll have to parse your datetime data in ISO-8601 standard to make your browser parse it as UTC, if you parse your data in a different format it will assumes local time zone:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

> **Differences in assumed time zone**
>
> Given a date string of "March 7, 2014", parse() assumes a local time
>   zone, but given an ISO format such as "2014-03-07" it will assume a
>   time zone of UTC (ES5 and ECMAScript 2015). Therefore Date objects
>   produced using those strings may represent different moments in time
>   depending on the version of ECMAScript supported unless the system is
>   set with a local time zone of UTC. This means that two date strings
>   that appear equivalent may result in two different values depending on
>   the format of the string that is being converted.